# Apache: Forward to another port only for one website

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, virtualhost, reverse-proxy, gitlab

I did install GitLab on my Apache server using this script https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3626 and I configured Apache to forward everything incoming on port 8080 to port 3000 like this:

```
<VirtualHost *80>

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            Allow Override
    </Directory>

    .
    .
    .

</VirtualHost>
```

However I would like to forward everything only for a particular website I host on this webserver. Can this be done?

I'm quite new into these things, if something is not clear, please ask.

Answer (score 1):

Your config above does not match what you say that you are doing. But in answer to your question - yes, it can, you set up a `VirtualHost` for that one website and put the ProxyPass and other proxy directives in that virtualhost. There's a sample config for a similar issue in [Running two PHP versions (5.3 & 5.2) at the same time](https://serverfault.com/questions/520842/running-two-php-versions-5-3-5-2-at-the-same-time/520847#520847) .

I would advise you to spend some time reading the documentation for both [virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/) and [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html). It will more than pay off in fewer misunderstandings.